# How to catch JSON Error in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Follow this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5 , I make simple App like that:

```
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"] 

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kLatestKivaLoansURL];
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];
        NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"loans"];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        NSLog(@"loans: %@",latestLoans); 

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
            self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        });

    });

    return YES;
}

@end
```

When Network not OK or JSON link Error, I get same break: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil"

How to catch this Error? I just want to display an Alert message, not break.

How many kind of Errors when parse JSON data?

Comment: Don't pass a nil data parameter.  It's easy enough to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement a check on `NSData* data` whether it is nil or not? If its nil then you should not run the code line

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];
```

as you are trying to convert `nil` data into `Dictionary`.

You can also check network availability by implementing Reachability classes in you code. A sample application demonstrates how to use the SystemConfiguration framework to monitor the network state of an iPhone or iPod touch

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks!I'll except your answer! Could you explain more what's type of errors can we catch and how to catch them?

Comment: You have already implemented NSError *error for error fetching. You just need to populate the error                                      if (error != NULL) {
    // populate the error object with the details
    *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Json error" code:200 userInfo:details];
}                                                                   I was looking JSON official page http://www.json.org/ and found the validator:                                      http://jsonlint.com/. This one is for browser.